How to intercept network calls with selenium typescript?
I am using typescript, packages
"selenium-webdriver": "^4.8.1",
"@types/selenium-webdriver": "^4.1.11",

and chromedriver.
I am interested that after opening a particular site to "listen to the network calls".
Example
await driver.get('https://example.com");

Now I want to intercept all the request and responses AJAX ones that this site is doing.
I need to fetch the API response for a particular url and proceed with the assertion logic of my selenium test.
How can I achieve that?
What I tried:
I used "browsermob-proxy": "^1.0.13", without success

type Proxy = {
    host: string;
    port: number;
    start: () => Promise<void>;
    cbHAR: (
        url: string,
        doSeleniumStuff: (proxy: Proxy, cb: () => void) => void,
        cb: (err: Error | null, data: string) => void,
    ) => void;
    getHAR: () => {
        log: {
            entries: {
                // @ts-ignore
                request: any;
                // @ts-ignore
                response: any;
            }[];
        };
    };
    doHAR: (url: string, cb: (err: Error | null, data: string) => void) => void;
};

const proxy = new browsermob.Proxy()
proxy.start(); // always failed also doHar etc


Thanks in advance

I would try to establish a connection to the browser using Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP) and after enabling the network you can subscribe to the requestWillBeSent and responseReceived events.
I suggest you to use chrome-remote-interface to make it easier. Although it can be done using Selenium Webdriver too although is not officially supported yet.
Example using chrome-remote-interface:
First configure the port in Selenium in the Chrome options:
options.addArguments('--remote-debugging-port=9222');

Then you can connect to that port using CDP and subscribe to the requests events:
import CDP from 'chrome-remote-interface';

async function listenToNetworkCalls() {
  let client: CDP.Client | undefined;

  try {
    // Connect to the Chrome DevTools Protocol
    client = await CDP({ port: 9222 });

    // Extract the domains we need
    const { Network } = client;

    // Enable the network domain
    await Network.enable();

    // Subscribe to the requestWillBeSent event
    Network.requestWillBeSent((params) => {
      console.log('Request:', params.request);
    });

    // Subscribe to the responseReceived event
    Network.responseReceived((params) => {
      console.log('Response:', params.response);
    });

  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error:', err);
  }
}

